# Few errors in my C code?

Tags: c, unix

I'm stuck on my C program and I have a few errors in it. I have very little experience with C, and I'm writing a program to simulate the wc command in Linux/Unix. I have tried a lot of things to try to get my code to work, but nothing has helped me so far. Here's my code with the errors in it:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Enumerators */
enum { FALSE, TRUE };
enum { STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR };

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096];
#define NAME_SIZE 12];
#define MAX_LINES 100000];

/* Globals */
char *fileName = NULL;
char tmpName [NAME_SIZE];
int option = FALSE;
int charOption = FALSE; // There is not a character option
int wordOption = FALSE; // There is not a word option
int lineOption = FALSE; // There is not a line option
int standardInput = FALSE; 
int c = 0; // Character to be scanned
int nl = 0; // Number of lines
int nw = 0; // Number of words
int nc = 0; // Number of characters
int fileOffset = 0;
int fd;

parseCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-')
           processOptions(argv[i]);
        else if (fileName == NULL)
           fileName = argv[i];
        else
           usageError();
    }
    standardInput = (fileName == NULL);
}

processOptions(char* str) {
    int j;

    for (j = 1; str[j] != NULL; j++) {
    switch (str[j]) {
        case 'c': /* Count number of characters in a file */
          charOption = TRUE; /* Option has been supplied in command line */
          while (getchar() != EOF) /* Scan characters until end of file */
            nc++; /* Increment number of characters */
          break;
        case 'l': /* Count number of lines in a file */
          charOption = TRUE; /* Option has been supplied in command line */
          while ((c == getchar()) != 'Z') /* Scan chars until end of file */
            if (c == '\n')
              nl++;
          break;
        case 'w': /* Count number of words in a file */
          charOption = TRUE; /* Option has been supplied in command line */
          int state = 0;
          while ((c == getchar() != 'Z')) {
            ++nc;
            if (c == '\n') /* New line */
              nl++; /* Increment number of lines */
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') /* Word separators */
              state = 0;
            else if (state == 0) {
              state = 1;
              ++nw; /* Increment number of words */
            }
          } /* End while */
          break;
        default: 
          usageError(); /* An error occurred */
          break;
        }
    }
}

/* Too many arguments supplied */
usageError() {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]"\)n"");
    exit(1);
;}

/* Main program */
main(argc, argv[])
char* argv[];
({
    int i; 

    processOptions(str); /* Read options from command line */

    int flag[3] = {lineOption,wordOption,charOption}; /* Count options */
    int stats[3] = {nl,nw,nc}; /* Number of lines, words, and chars in file */

    if (!option) /* No options have been supplied; print number of lines, words, and characters in a file */
       printf("%d %d %d %s\n",nl,nw,nc,fileName);
    else { /* Options have been supplied, read them */
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          if (flag[i]) /* If a specific argument is supplied */
            printf("%d ",stats[i]); /* Print number of lines, words, and/or chars, depending on the argument(s) supplied */
       }
    printf("%s\n",fileName); /* Print file name */
    }
    return 0; /* Exit program */
}
```

Then when I go to compile my program, I get these errors/warnings:

```
mywc.c:19:24: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘]’ token
 char tmpName [NAME_SIZE]
                        ^
mywc.c:29:24: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘]’ token
 int lineStart[MAX_LINES]
                        ^
mywc.c: In function ‘processOptions’:
mywc.c:50:24: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     for (j = 1; str[j] != NULL; j++) {
                        ^
mywc.c: In function ‘usageError’:
mywc.c:86:5: error: stray ‘\’ in program
     fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]"\)n"");
     ^
mywc.c:86:52: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘n’
     fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]"\)n"");
                                                    ^
mywc.c:86:55: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
     fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]"\)n"");
                                                       ^
mywc.c: At top level:
mywc.c:90:16: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token
 main(argc, argv[])
                ^
mywc.c:92:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
 ({
  ^
```

As I said above, I tried a lot of things that SEEMED correct, but these gave me errors as well. I would appreciate any help I could get with these errors, as well as a few hints to help me get my program to run correctly.

PS Assuming I have a test.txt file that looks like this:

```
Hello World!
```

Here's a sample output of what my program should look like:

```
./mywc -c test.txt
12 /* Assuming that test.txt contains 8 characters */

./mywc -l test.txt
1

./mywc test.txt
1 2 12 test.txt /* 1 is number of lines, 2 is number of words, 12 is number of chars */
```

Comment: 0) ex `#define NAME_SIZE 12];` --> `#define NAME_SIZE 12` , remove `];`

Comment: 1) `"Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]"\)n""` --> `"Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]\n"`

Comment: 2) `main(argc, argv[])
char* argv[];
({` --> `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you're not posting an answer bc you think the question isn't ok?

Comment: 3) `processOptions(str);` , `str` ?? maybe `argv[1]`

Comment: 4) `str[j] != NULL` --> `str[j] != '\0'`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY probably ./mywc ---->" -c test.txt "<------- is str

Comment: @ysaditya `processOptions` check option, not parse file name.

Comment: 5) and has  more problem

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i showed the same thing  with arrows ( maybe not so clear )

Comment: @ysaditya `argv[2]` if  file name exists. see Usage.

Answer (score 1):

These:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096];
#define NAME_SIZE 12];
#define MAX_LINES 100000];
```

will give parse errors when you use the symbols as if they were plain integers. Remove the trailing square bracket and semicolon from each.

This:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]"\)n"");
```

should be

```
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mywc -lwc [fileName]\n");
```

This:

```
main(argc, argv[])
```

should be:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
```